# What is causing this artifact?

Tags: transparency, artifacts

Just wondering what is cause this artifact? Using cycles. running Blender 2.8

I have built a heat sink on top of a chip. as my camera is zooming out, the opacity of the heat sink is changing to a solid look.

This only happens for two frames.
[image]

How do I fix this? I've already increase the light bounces for transparency and transmission.

your suggestions would be great.

Thank you

William

Comment: have you enabled motion blur? it looks like it can creata artifacts...

Comment: This is very specific, it would really help if you could share your .blend file.